# High CPU usage with grunt 1.0.3 and sailsjs

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, grunt-contrib-watch

Here's my watch.js file :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.config.set('watch', {
assets: {

  // Assets to watch:
  files: [
    'assets/**/*',
    'tasks/pipeline.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!assets/images/**' // <- Added this line to stop watching
  ],

  // When assets are changed:
  tasks: [
    'syncAssets',
    'linkAssets'
  ]
}
});
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691475/sails-js-application-driving-cpu-usage-to-100) to reduce the folder grunt watches for change but to no avail.
Also, I deleted the task folder along with Gruntfile.js file to stop using grunt but doing htop on the server still shows grunt hogging the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the watch script `options : { interval: 1000 }` in `Gruntfile.js`